# Convert a bytearray in hex to an IP address python

Tags: python, ip, hex, byte

I have an ip address in this format

```
b'\xd4\xfbuW'
```

I know that this is an actual IP address, but I don't know how I can print it as a normal (like `192.168.1.1`) address and also store it in my memory as a string. How can I decode this hex bytearray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) module functions, for instance:

```
import socket

ip_string = '192.168.1.1'
print(socket.inet_aton(ip_string))
print(socket.inet_ntoa(socket.inet_aton(ip_string)))
print(socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, '192.168.1.1'))
print(socket.inet_ntop(
    socket.AF_INET, socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, '192.168.1.1')))

packed_ip = b'\xd4\xfbuW'
print(socket.inet_ntoa(b'\xd4\xfbuW'))
```

Output

```
b'\xc0\xa8\x01\x01'
192.168.1.1
b'\xc0\xa8\x01\x01'
192.168.1.1
212.251.117.87
```

As you can see, `192.168.1.1` would correspond to `\xC0\xA8\x01\x01` and `b'\xd4\xfbuW'` would be `212.251.117.87`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the socket module.

If you have Python 3.6 or above you can use:

```
print('.'.join(f'{c}' for c in b'\xd4\xfbuW'))
```

otherwise

```
print('.'.join(str(c) for c in b'\xd4\xfbuW'))
```